# CppCheck suppress obsolete function

Tags: static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I cannot inline suppress obsoleteFunctiosgets warning from cppcheck.
I tried:

// cppcheck-suppress obsoleteFunctionsgets

with no success.

Did any of you experience this warning?
Any hint?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *--inline-suppr* on the command line also. Otherwise the comment is ignored.

```
daniel@dator:~/cppcheck$ ./cppcheck --enable=all 1.c
Checking 1.c...
[1.c:4]: (style) Obsolete function 'gets' called. It is recommended to use the function 'fgets' instead.
daniel@dator:~/cppcheck$ ./cppcheck --enable=all --inline-suppr 1.c
Checking 1.c...
daniel@dator:~/cppcheck$
```

Personally.. I prefer to use *--suppress* or *--suppressions-list* instead of *--inline-suppr*. I don't like to clutter my code with such comments.